# Security of Isolated Storage on Windows Phone 7 and Network Transfers

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, encryption, isolatedstorage

In my game I plan to save the users highest score to then be transferred to my server at a later time, I was planning to do this by saving the score in a .txt file in Isolated Storage.

What precautions should I take to avoid users from editing the file itself or being able to spoof packets to trick the server into saving fake scores?

I'm considering encrypting the data before saving in a way my server can read later on.

So how secure is Isolated Storage?
What encryption should I look at implementing considering my App is .NET(C#) and my server uses PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ProtectedData`, and store the `byte[]` to `IsolatedStorage`.

[ProtectedData Class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx)

Edit: If you want this to work serverside, encrypt with, say using `AesManaged` using a key. use `ProtectedData` to store the key for your AES encryption. That way, the user cannot find out your key.

Comment: That protected class is a great thanks, but I won't be able to use any .NET encryption classes as I need to write PHP to de-crypt. I think I may write the AES encryption myself though.

Comment: @Joel I don't know the magic behind it, but I work with a client and I use the AesManaged class to communicate to a Java servlet.

Comment: Yeah, looking as AES I think it would be really difficult to try and get my head around, but AES is a standard so theoretically it should be possible to use classes in PHP and .Net together